# Sorting a dataframe in PySpark without sql functions

Tags: python, sorting, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some trouble printing out this query with the months sorted in proper order.

Is there a pyspark function command to format the month column in descending order? (without using sql commands)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from operator import add

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

rows = sc.textFile("data.csv")
data = rows.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
header = data.first()

q = data.filter(lambda line: line != header)\
        .map(lambda x:(x[1], 1))\
        .reduceByKey(add)\
        .sortByKey(True)\
        .collect()

sqlContext.createDataFrame(q, ['Month','Total number of operated flights']).show()

+-----+--------------------------------+
|Month|Total number of operated flights|
+-----+--------------------------------+
|    1|                          621559|
|   10|                          629992|
|   11|                          605149|
|   12|                          614139|
|    2|                          565604|
|    3|                          639209|
|    4|                          614648|
|    5|                          631609|
|    6|                          629280|
|    7|                          648560|
|    8|                          653279|
|    9|                          600187|
+-----+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the month column is treated as string. There are several ways to achieve the correct order. For instance, you can cast the column to `int` on the RDD call and use `sortByKey(False)` for the descending order:

```
q = data.filter(lambda line: line != header)\
    .map(lambda x:(int(x[1]), 1))\
    .reduceByKey(add)\
    .sortByKey(False)\
    .collect()
```

I'm not quite this will match your expectations, but certainly you don't necessarily need to invoke `collect()` to make DF from RDD - you can achieve that by running:

```
df = data.filter(lambda line: line != header)\
 .map(lambda x:(int(x[1]), 1))\
 .reduceByKey(add)\
 .sortByKey(False)
 .toDF()
```

You can do the casting with the DataFrame API as well with `df.withColumn('Month', df['Month'].as(pyspark.sql.types.StringType())`, but you've stated you don't want to use Spark SQL.